# How to link two Jlists

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jlist

I have two Jlists of vectors filled with data extracted from a mysql db. What I want is when the user select an item (menu) from Jlist1 (which I called menuList) Jlist2 (which I called productList) must display the products of that menu and other things, such as the ability to insert a new product in THAT menu or in a new menu just created.
I've accomplished this task in a way which I think is weak, by using some boolean variables which tells if the user is inserting a product in an existing menu or in a newly created one. Please, can you suggest me a better solution (if exists)? Here is an extract of the most significant part of the code, this is the method which saves a new product in the db:

```
private void bAddProdActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    //If new menu is saved, get the new menu's Id

    if (newMenuIsSaved == true) {
        Product newProduct = new Product();
        newMenuId = DBConnection.getNewMenuId();
        newProduct.setMenuId(newMenuId);
        newProduct.setProductName(productName.getText());
        if (checkPPriceValidity(productPrice.getText(), newProduct)) {
            int result = DBConnection.insertProduct(newProduct);
            if (result == 1) {
                reloadProductList();

                disableProductButtons();
            }
        }

    } else {
        Product newProduct = new Product();
        //If a new menu wasn't saved, get the menuId from the selected one (from menuList):
        Menu selectedMenu = (Menu) menuList.getSelectedValue();
        newProduct.setMenuId(selectedMenu.getMenuId());
        newProduct.setProductName(productName.getText());
        if (checkPPriceValidity(productPrice.getText(), newProduct)) {
            int result = DBConnection.insertProduct(newProduct);
            if (result == 1) {
                reloadProductList();
                newMenuIsSaved = false;
                disableProductButtons();
                bNewProduct.setEnabled(true);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the method reloadProductList():

```
private void reloadProductList() {
    modelProductList.clear();

    if (newMenuIsSaved) {
        Vector<Product> productVoices = DBConnection.fillProductList(newMenuId);
        for (int i = 0; i < productVoices.size(); i++) {
            modelProductList.addElement((Product) productVoices.get(i));
        }
    } else {
        Vector<Product> productVoices = DBConnection.fillProductList(selectedMenuId);
        for (int i = 0; i < productVoices.size(); i++) {
            modelProductList.addElement((Product) productVoices.get(i));
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to add a [`ListSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) to `menuList` and have the handler set the *other* list's model to display the details for the selected row.

Comment: Thank you, but can you give me further details or maybe any examples?